# Adapt width of 3rd block in a Row with CSS

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I just come to an issue that I first thought of easy. I may just not see the simple solution here.

What I have is:

```
__________________________________
|           parent block         |
| block1 | block2 |   textblock  |
----------------------------------
```

The parent block has a fixed min-width but is otherwise adapting to the browser's width.
block1 and block2 have fixed widths.
textblock has text inside which should take the remaining space available here...
Now the problem is, that textblock's content may be too much for one line, so I would like it to show multiple lines inside of textblock.
However, as I currently just have them positions by using inline-blocks, the textblock just goes into the next line.

wanted:

```
__________________________________
|           parent block         |
|        |        |some larger   |
| block1 | block2 |text that     |
|        |        |wraps arouind |
----------------------------------
```

but gotten:

```
__________________________________
|           parent block         |
| block1 | block2 |              |
|some larger text that wraps     |
|around                          |
----------------------------------
```

I guess a blind table would solve this, but I really try avoiding such things...

A minimalistic examlpe is probably not necessary, but here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style type='text/css'>
h2.wrapper{width:50%;min-width:200px;background-color:#aff;}
div.block1{vertical-align:middle;width:50px;background-color:#faf;display:inline-block;height:50px;}
div.block2{vertical-align:middle;width:50px;background-color:#ffa;display:inline-block;height:50px;}
div.textblock{width:auto;background-color:#afa;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
</style></head><body><h2 class='wrapper'>
<div class='block1'>block1</div>
<div class='block2'>block2</div>
<span class='textblock'>some larger text that wraps around</span>
</h2></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XSFfv/2/) for you.

The magic attribute is:

```
float:left;
```

I hope it's exactly what you wanted.

Comment: I like your answer better than my own, for the record.

Comment: Thanks. ;)
I hope @Julian likes it too.

Comment: How exactly is this behavior different than making everything `display=inline-block` ? if I make the container of those three blocks too small, they will also just make a second line. I probably didn't express it well, but I want the 3rd block to adapt to the container's size, so the text gets wrapped inside, if the 3rd box is too small. but in any size of the parent container, it should still be one line (assuming the width is always enough to actually display at least one word of the 3rd block)...

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to get. If you could explain it to me I think I'm able to do that css. Do you want a fixed height for the 3rd block? You're kinda confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, I spaced your code a bit. I also noticed that div.textblock wasn't giving class='textblock' it's attributes because textblock was a span, not a div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type='text/css'>
h2.wrapper{width:50%;min-width:200px;background-color:#aff;}
.block1{vertical-align:middle;width:10%;background-color:#faf;display:inline-block;height:50px;}
.block2{vertical-align:middle;width:10%;background-color:#ffa;display:inline-block;height:50px;}
.textblock{width:30%;background-color:#afa;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
div.wrap{display:inline-block;white-space:wrap;}
</style>

</head>
    <body>
        <h2 class='wrapper'>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="block1">block1</div>
                <div class="block2">block2</div>
                <span class="textblock">some larger text that wraps around</span>
            </div>
        </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

I wrapped it all in a .wrap class div in order for everything to display in one inline-block instead of their own. Not sure if that even matters, but I'm OCD. What mainly makes the textblock display as a wrap is the 30% width. Since your main div is 50% of the webpage, you would just need to make your inner divs add up to 50%.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! the problem is, I have buttons and selects and stuff in the first two buttons, so fixed widths would be really nice there... and if part if this those first two are fixed then the last one cannot have a fitting percentage for filling the remaining space... But thanks for fixing the css-issue^^ I was already wondering why thy display-behavior was another wrong than the wrong I described^^

Comment: Oh I see. I have a problem with not thinking ahead haha. No problem with the CSS though! :)